# Merge duplicated relationship between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j Version 3.5.4 and doing the Introduction Course Exercises on the movies dataset. I noticed that I accidentally introduced duplicates in some relationships as shown:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
 WHERE m.title = 'Forrest Gump'
 RETURN p,m,r
```

[image]
[image]

How can I combine them so I just keep one of the duplicates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tail and collect functions to remove the duplicates:

- Collect will get all relationships
- Tail will get all items in the collection EXCEPT the first one
- Foreach will do a loop in all items in collection | then delete it

Here it is:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
 WHERE m.title = 'Forrest Gump'
 WITH tail(collect(r)) as coll , p
 FOREACH (x in coll| DELETE x)
```